# Place image on HTML map area

Tags: html

I have this [map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRP8S.jpg). All fields on this map are cuted with HTML map areas. How can I place image in one field(area) through map? Example: this [building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3mtx.png).

Map code:

```
<img src="slike/pregled/plangrada.jpg" width="800" height="480" usemap="#mapagrad">
<map name="mapagrad">
<area id="p1" shape="poly" coords="611,88,705,41,799,88,705,135" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p2" shape="poly" coords="-28,129,87,72,202,129,87,187" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p3" shape="poly" coords="347,154,407,124,467,154,407,184" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p4" shape="poly" coords="263,197,323,167,383,197,323,227" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p5" shape="poly" coords="431,197,491,167,551,197,491,227" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p6" shape="poly" coords="178,239,238,209,298,239,238,269" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p7" shape="poly" coords="515,238,575,208,635,238,575,268" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p8" shape="poly" coords="94,281,154,251,214,281,154,311" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p9" shape="poly" coords="607,292,779,206,951,292,779,378" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p10" shape="poly" coords="11,322,71,292,131,322,71,352" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p11" shape="poly" coords="179,323,239,293,299,323,239,353" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p12" shape="poly" coords="516,323,576,293,636,323,576,353" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p13" shape="poly" coords="258,362,322,330,386,362,322,394" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p14" shape="poly" coords="431,365,491,335,551,365,491,395" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p15" shape="poly" coords="512,398,657,326,802,398,657,471" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p16" shape="poly" coords="-62,394,109,309,280,394,109,480" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
<area id="p18" shape="poly" coords="346,407,406,377,466,407,406,437" onclick="izaberi(this)" href="#">
</map>
```

Comment: what about posting some code?

Comment: i posted map code now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because the image map is really just to identify links on the image. I recommend creating a wrapper around your map:

```
<div class="map"></div>
```

And placing your buildings on top of your image with position: absolute:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvNQQr